# Error converting data type varchar to date when running Excel macro

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I receive error 'Error converting data type varchar to date' when running VBA macro in excel. Why is this happening?

```
'Set and Excecute SQL Command'

 strSQL = sqlString        

  sqlString = "SET NOCOUNT ON exec spExcelGetCompositionChanges" _
                        & "" & "'" _
                        & "" & Index_RIC & "" _
                        & "', " _
                        & "'" _
                        & "" & Start_Date & "" _
                        & "', " _
                        & "'" _
                        & "" & End_Date & "" _
                        & "'"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  There is probably no way this question can be answered. The error you are getting is probably coming back from the stored proc you're executing. Here's [some info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about asking good questions.

Comment: Use a proper `ADODB.Command` with `CommandType` set to `adStoredProc`, then give it proper `ADODB.Parameter` values, and let the server deal with the quotes and parameter types. This isn't a SQL *command*, it's a SQL Injection vulnerability ;-)

Comment: I had a similar error with this query in VBA "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string": sqlString = "select CalcDate, EventType as [CA Type], EventDesc, ExDate, FirstEntryDate, Paf as [PAF], NewEodNos, CurrentClosingNos, NewClosingNos, CurrentFif,NewFif [FIF]" _
& " from Staging.[msci].[tblChangesInTheMsciIndices] chg " _
& " join tblCodePivot cp on cp.Isin = chg.Isin " _
& "" & searchStr1 & "" _
& " and ExDate >= " _
& "" & searchStr2 & "" _

Comment: Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57977138/edit) and do not post code in hard to read comments. Once done, come back and delete this comment.